# how to set keypress for input only number with %

Tags: javascript

i don't know to set keypress on javascript for input only number and %
example 100% or 50%

```
       -----------------------------
```

Discount : |             50%           |
           -----------------------------

Answer (score 0):

A little hard to understand, but i think i decrypted your request :D

```js
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener( 'input', function() {
  lastValid = this.dataset.lastValid || '';
  
  let start = this.selectionStart + '';
  let end = this.selectionEnd + '';
  
  console.log( this.value );
  console.log( this.value.match(/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*%?$/) );
  
  if( this.value.match(/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*%?$/) !== null ) {
    this.dataset.lastValid = this.value;
  } else {
    this.value = lastValid;
    start = end -= 1;
  }
  this.selectionStart = start;
  this.selectionEnd = end;
} );
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput">
```

**EDIT** updated for float %

**EDIT2** fixed: can be empty now

**EDIT3** fixed: last_valid usage

Comment: then please tell me, what do you need?

Comment: ok true thank sir. but you can help me to set it again. example i input it 100% but 1%00 or %100  and  or 100%%  is not true. please help me. thank

Comment: fiexed it. % only at the end, maybe not the most elegant way to do this

Comment: it is can't input float number

Comment: @CheaThaily  now it can :)

Comment: @CheaThaily fixed it :)